# How can I display distance markings on a line (Mapbox-gl)?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, turfjs

I want to display kilometers markings along a route drawn with addlayer: line. With @turf/along, I can calculate the coordinates for the distance markings, but what would be a good way of displaying them on the map? Non-turf related methods are also welcome.

I want to display the coordinates either on the route line itself, or below the line between a certain meter span, like per 100m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my purposes, I wanted to display a distance label along the route line for each full kilometer (that's why routeDistance is floored).

```
//distanceLabel object
var distanceLabels = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": []
}

//added it as a map source
map.addSource('distanceLabels', {
  "type": "geojson",
  "data": distanceLabels
})

//added distancLabels as a map layer
map.addLayer({
  "id": "distanceLabels",
  "type": "symbol",
  "source": "distanceLabels",
  "paint": {
    'text-color': '#000000'
  },
  "layout": {
    'symbol-placement': 'point',
    'text-font': ['Open Sans Regular','Arial Unicode MS Regular'],
    'text-field': '{distance}\n{unit}',
    'text-anchor': 'center',
    'text-justify': 'center',
    'text-size': 13,
    'icon-allow-overlap': true,
    'icon-ignore-placement': true
  }
})


//render labels function
 renderDistanceMarkers() {
  var unit = this.isMetric == true ? 'kilometers' : 'miles'
  var unitShort = this.isMetric == true ? 'km' : 'mi'

  //calculate line distance to determine the placement of the labels
  var routeDistance = turf.length(route.features[0], {units: unit})

  //rounding down kilometers (11.76km -> 11km)
  routeDistance = Math.floor(routeDistance)
  var points = []

  //only draw labels if route is longer than 1km
  if(routeDistance !== 0) {
    // Draw an arc between the `origin` & `destination` of the two points

    for (var i = 0; i < routeDistance + 1; i++) {
      var segment = turf.along(route.features[0], i, {units: unit})

      if(i !== 0) { //Skip the initial point (start coordinate)
          points.push({
              "type": "Feature",
              "properties": {'unit': unitShort},
              "geometry": {
                  "type": "Point",
                  "coordinates": segment.geometry.coordinates
              }
          })
      }

    }

    distanceLabels.features = points

    //update distances for the label texts
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      distanceLabels.features[i].properties.distance = i + 1 //First one would be 0
    }

    //render now labels
    map.getSource('distanceLabels').setData(distanceLabels)

  }
},
```

Comment: Do you have a working example of how you achieved this or were you placed this code?  I'm also trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new layer of type  [`symbol`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layers-symbol) for your distance label.

Since you already are able to calculate its coordinates, all you have left to do is create a source with these coordinates and connect it to a layout with the following fields:

- `text-field` with the distance string (eg. `'text-field': '{distance}km'` if you set the distance in the source properties)
- `text-offset` with the relative offset relative to its center. NB: the unit is `ems`, not meters.

Example (not tested):

```
{
  id: 'distance-label',
  type: 'symbol',
  source: 'distance-labels',
  paint: {
    'text-color': '#00f'
  },
  layout: {
    'symbol-placement': 'point',
    'text-font': ['Open Sans Regular','Arial Unicode MS Regular'],
    'text-field': '{distance}km',
    'text-offset': [0, -0.6],
    'text-anchor': 'center',
    'text-justify': 'center',
    'text-size': 12,
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you MeltedPenguin, this helped a lot!